# Get link of all objects in AWS S3 bucket in a spreadsheet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

I have uploaded few images in my AWS S3 bucket, with public access. 
I need the urls of these, is there any way to do this, instead of manually one by one?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking.  How do you programmatically interrogate a bucket for its objects?  Generate (one-signed) URLs?  Programmatically build an Excel spreadsheet?  We will most likely need to see what code you have tried and what about that code isn't working.

Comment: I edited the question. Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 6):

This is easy to with your own program here is a sample program with https://github.com/minio/minio-py library.

If you know which prefix you have uploaded them to you can list them with prefixed delimiter.

```
from minio import Minio

client = Minio('https://s3.amazonaws.com',
               access_key='**************',
               secret_key='**************')

# List all object paths in bucket that begin with hello.
objects = client.list_objects('your-bucket', prefix='your-prefix',
                              recursive=True)
for obj in objects:
    url = 'https://{0}.s3.amazonaws.com/{1}'.format(obj.bucket_name,
                                                    obj.object_name.encode('utf-8'))
    print(url)
```

Comment: from minio import Minio
import csv
client=Minio('https://s3.amazonaws.com',access_key='access_key',secret_key='secret_key')
objects = client.list_objects('crowd-flower-1', prefix='prefixName',recursive=True)
with open('img.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        for obj in objects:
     url = 'https://{0}.s3.amazonaws.com/{1}'.format(obj.bucket_name,obj.object_name.encode('utf-8'))
            print ', '.join(obj.object_name,url)

Comment: Trying it out locally.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/harshavardhana/427b2e2b59f908df5405 - here you go.  You were opening a file in "rb" it should have been "wb".